# What are common implementations for containers with polymorphic data?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

Let's say I create an abstract class Entity, and then multiple subclasses of it, each one with its parameters and functons, but sharing a common interface thanks to Entity. That's so far the most common example in object oriented programming.

What happens internally when I create a vector of Entity values and tell it to reserve (ensure capacity without resizing) for N elements. How does it know the size, if the size could be any value? Is the common part being stored in the vector and then a pointer to a subclass specific part as well? If so, where would that pointer end up declared in the Heap? That would be highly detrimental for the cache performance.

Finally, does this have any relation with POD and non POD types?

Comment: You should really add a code snippet demonstrating just what you mean. A *compilable* code snippet, which you try to run yourself too. Also, possibly related reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the vector contains `Entity` values, then it contains values of type `Entity`, not any subclass. Since `Entity` is abstract, such a vector can't be instantiated.

If you want polymorphism, you'll have to store pointers to objects stored elsewhere, or smart pointers if you want the vector to manage their lifetime as it would its elements.

Comment: It's insane how many graduate I see in interviews who do not know this. I really don't get understand what they teach in "C++" courses in college. Apparently how to implement linked-list with malloc..

Comment: After reading your answer I realize how dumb my question was in the first place, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Once Abstract classes come into play, POD goes right out the window.  You are working with everything through pointers.  You don't care about the size of the objects because it's not a vector of objects, it's a vector of pointers to the objects.

If the vector 'owns' the memory(sounds like your case), then the code would look like this...

```
// Declaration
std::vector <Entity *> ent_vector;

// Inserting into the vector
ent_vector.push_back(new EntityImpl());

// In a destructor somewhere...
for (std::vector<Entity *>::iterator i = ent_vector.begin(); i != ent_vector.end(); ++i)
{
  delete *i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not explicit support for this sort of thing in C++. You must (as explained in Mike's answer) access the polymorphic objects via pointers to envoke the polymorphic behaviour. That means you must store pointers in your container. If you want, as usual, your container to also manage the lifetime of the objects, you should use `unique_ptr`s.

You could create your own little polymorphic container along the lines of

```
template<typename AbstractType>
class poly_vector
: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractType>>
{
  typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractType>> base;
public:
  using base::begin;                               // public access
  using base::end;                                 //   to some vector
  using base::size;                                //   functionality

  poly_vector() = default;                         // default ctor
  poly_vector(poly_vector&&) = default;            // move, but
  poly_vector(poly_vector const&) = delete;        // no copy
  // add another object at the end
  template<typename DerivedType, typename...Args>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<AbstractType,DerivedType>::value>::type
  emplace_back(Args&&..args)
  {
    base::emplace_back(new DerivedType(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

However, the objects pointed to by `begin()` are again pointers (`unique_ptr`s actually), so the semantics to access the polymorphic objects is a bit unusual.
Also, the semantics for `emplace_back` are unusual: you must provide the `DerivedType` explicitly as template parameter as in `myvec.emplace_back<Dervied>(arg1,arg2);`

Of course, you can elaborate on the above ideas, including an iterator type that avoids the double derefencing, and full allocator support etc ...